# I want to prove $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{n^2} i^n = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{4n^2} (-1)^n $

Tags: summation, infinity

I want to prove
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{n^2} i^n = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{4n^2} (-1)^n 
\end{align}

It is quite weird.. even I substitute $n=2k$, then $dn=2$ so we are considering different sums...

This comes from [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, then $q^{n^2}i^n+q^{(-n)^2}i^{-n}=0$ and therefore\begin{align}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}i^n&=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}n=-\infty\\[-1ex]n\text{ even}\end{array}}^\infty q^{n^2}i^n\\&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{(2n)^2}i^{2n}\\&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{4n^2}(-1)^n.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks I got it. It's due to $-\infty$ to $\infty $ sum. Great!

Comment: Indeed. If it was $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ instead, my argument would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the sum over even $n$ and the sum over odd $n$. Use the fact that $i^{2n+1}=- i^{-(2n+1)}$ so the sum over odd $n$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=2k+1$ we have $$i^n+i^{-n}=i^{2k+1}+i^{-2k-1}=(-1)^k\cdot i+(-1)^k\cdot (-i)=0$$
so $$q^{n^2}i^n+q^{(-n)^2}i^{-n}=0\ \ \text{for all odd } n.$$